# How to Execute a Script in url of your site

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to Execute a javascript function from the URL?

Something like: `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?alert(HelloWorld);`

That when this url is visited then it should run the script.

Comment: The question here is probably not how, but why. What's your use case? :o

Comment: You can do by using the `GET` to get the query string... there may be other ways.. But i know only one..

Comment: the question is not `HOW?` the question is `WHY????`

Comment: @SiGanteng ,@STT LCU : actually i wanna to make my site capable of executing javascript through address bar or in other words wanna to convert to a site that is vulnerable to XSS.This is just for a Experimental Purpose.That i came to know and stop vulnerabilities against XSS.

Comment: @DeepakGupta just look at my answer. you'll be done in 30 seconds.

Comment: Getting a decent understanding of XSS and how to defend against it does not come from 30 seconds of observing a single example of an XSS security hole.

Answer (score 1):

On an arbitrary site? No, that would mean that browsers were creating a horrific [XSS security vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) on every site.

On your site? You could write a server side script to read the query string and inject it into a `<script>` element … which would give your site the aforementioned horrific XSS security vulnerability.

Comment: Quentin:ya thats true,it will work what you suggest but actually i wanna to make my site capable of executing javascript through address bar or in other words wanna to convert to a site that is vulnerable to XSS.This is just for a Experimental Purpose.That i cam know and stop vulnerabilities against XSS

Comment: If you want to experiment with running JavaScript from outside the page, then you are almost certainly better using the Console in the Developer Tools of whichever browser you use.

Comment: You could do it all in Javascript/HTML without server side scripting. (See my answer.) There is no reason to burdon the server with this. And even though you won't stop XSS (which is the reason I oppose the whole idea), doing it via server side will even make way for HTML injection.

Comment: Doing it client side will make way for HTML injection too, you just need to write JS that does innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible and would be a huge security issue.
Set the script in the landing page and run it once it's loaded

Comment: actually, you can run javascript from ajax... search for JSONP on google ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is an incredibly stupid thing to do. But you can... You won't need PHP. Just use Javascript.

In the <body onload=""> just put eval(decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substr(1))); like this:

```
<body onload="eval(decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substr(1)));">
```

Url should be like http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?alert('HelloWorld');

(So lose the <script></script> in the url)

Answer (score 0):

You can define it on your PHP file!

Your PHP file :

```
if($_GET['script'] == "1")
{
...do script
}
```

in your url :

```
http://youraddress.com/index.php?script=1
```

Customize it for yourself.
wish helpful